# Треугольник на css. Border закрывает другие блоки

Tags: css

Есть подменю, где в вёрстке используется треугольник на css. Проблема в том что его прозрачные границы "закрывают" ссылки в подменю. Есть выход из этой ситуации? Может по-другому треугольник можно нарисовать?

```css
.menu__item {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  
}

.menu__item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu__item-activ{
  position:relative;
}
.menu__item-activ:after {

}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#efefef;
}

.submenu:before {
     content: ''; 
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 0; 
    top:0;
    border: 50px solid transparent; /* Прозрачные границы */
    border-top: 10px solid green; /* Добавляем треугольник */
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__item-link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item menu__item-activ">
    <a href="" class="menu__item-link">About</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item"> <a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu1</a> </li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu2</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__item-link">Catalog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `pointer-events`

```css
.menu__item {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  
}

.menu__item-link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu__item-activ{
  position:relative;
}
.menu__item-activ:after {

}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#efefef;
}

.submenu:before {
     content: ''; 
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 0; 
    top:0;
    border: 50px solid transparent; /* Прозрачные границы */
    border-top: 10px solid green; /* Добавляем треугольник */
    pointer-events:none; /* решение */
}
/*для наглядности*/
.submenu a:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__item-link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu__item menu__item-activ">
    <a href="" class="menu__item-link">About</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item"> <a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu1</a> </li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu2</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="" class="submenu-link">submenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__item-link">Catalog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Очень интересно. Спасибо!